# ASP.NET repeater in update panel

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I have a product entry screen where the items in the order are displayed inside a repeater control within an ajax update panel.  The repeater simulates a grid where every row is editable at once (so user can tab through the rows, updating many quantities, and then hitting one save button at the bottom).

Right now it works, but is a little too slow (way too slow over 100 items).  The repeater will have anywhere from 20-250 rows.  Is there a way to not have the entire repeater re-render when I just want to add one row?

Comment: thanks for that idea..but my users enter most of the items in one sitting, so won't I be in the same boat after the first item is entered in this extra area at the bottom?  I will have to refresh the main repeater eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you could add the second row into a new area, just below the main one, in a seperate ajax panel, and just consider it the same. You'll need to do some slightly additional work on your 'save' button, but in general it will work.

Comment: Make sure to make the 'UpdateMode' property of the outermost UpdatePanel to "conditional" if you nest UpdatePanels like this, otherwise you undo the purpose of the inner panel

Comment: I actually wasn't suggesting nesting; merely one after the other.